# microphyton:ERROR STATUS 1 with lib machine

Tags: python, pip, installation, setup.py, micropython

don't let me install the lib machine.

I have installed the new version of python 3.8X 64bit, and I need the machine library but it gives me error status 1 and then status 2.
Why does it happen to me and how do I solve this problem?

**HOW INSTALL MACHINE??**

````
  Using cached machine-0.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (4.2 kB)
Collecting pycrypto
  Using cached pycrypto-2.6.1.tar.gz (446 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: pycrypto
  Building wheel for pycrypto (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\javier.gutierrez\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\javier.gutierrez\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4736ysct\\pycrypto\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\javier.gutierrez\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4736ysct\\pycrypto\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\javier.gutierrez\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-bc38nqbl'
       cwd: C:\Users\javier.gutierrez\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4736ysct\pycrypto\
  Complete output (183 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8
  creating build\lib.win32-3.8\Crypto
.......................

    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\javier.gutierrez\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\javier.gutierrez\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4736ysct\\pycrypto\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\javier.gutierrez\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4736ysct\\pycrypto\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\javier.gutierrez\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-g2ah2ovt\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\javier.gutierrez\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\Include\pycrypto' Check the logs for full command output.```



_______________________________________________________________________________
[[[[[[[_You are therefore probably looking for another module, since you tagged micropython, maybe this one? neither does it allow me to install the upython lib._

_I have redrawn all and added the path besides checking that this 64bits_

**thanks for your help**]]]]]]]]

_________________________________________________________________________________


Collecting micropython-machine
  Using cached micropython-machine-0.2.tar.gz (1.7 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\javier.gutierrez\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d28uahkh\\micropython-machine\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\javier.gutierrez\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d28uahkh\\micropython-machine\_, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\javier.gutierrez\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d28uahkh\micropython-machine\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\javier.gutierrez\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-d28uahkh\micropython-machine\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\python\lib\tokenize.py", line 392, in open
        buffer = _builtin_open(filename, 'rb')
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\javier.gutierrez\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-d28uahkh\\micropython-machine\\setup.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.```
````

Comment: Did you leave out part of the error?

Comment: From your question it sounds as if you're trying to install the `machine` library from MicroPython into standard Python 3.8 running on a PC, is that correct? `machine` is for accessing [hardware-specific features](http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/library/machine.html) of an embedded board running MicroPython, so I don't see how that's supposed to work. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have already solved the bug, the library does not install me because it has it internally although it does not reflect it in the code.

Thanks for your help

Comment: @JOESABROSA You should post your fix as answer to your question so other may benefit from your problem solving. cheers!

Answer (score 1):

> I have installed the new version of python 3.8X 64bit

No, you have python 3.8 32 bit, as your path suggests:

c:\users\javier.gutierrez\appdata\local\programs\python\ **python38-32**

Also your error suggests that it is trying to build for 32 bit:

```
creating build\lib.win32
```

> Why does it happen to me

The module you are trying to install has `pycrypto` as a requirement, which has not been updated since 2014 and is only compatible up to python 3.5. It is also **insecure** and should not be used.

Looking at the module you are trying to install which is [this one](https://pypi.org/project/machine/#description), it is pretty much empty, containing only an example `setup.py` and an example `__init__.py`.

You are therefore probably looking for another module, since you tagged `micropython`, maybe [this one](https://pypi.org/project/micropython-machine/#description)?